# warning: operand types are incompatible ("int" and "void *")

Tags: c, operands

I am using a pgcc compiler to compile the following piece of code. I keep getting this warning and I am not sure what is wrong with it.
Here is the code, followed by the warning:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#ifdef _CRAY
int MEMALLOC (nextptr, size)
#else
#ifdef POST_UNDERSCORE
int memalloc_ (nextptr, size)
#else
int memalloc (nextptr, size)
#endif
#endif

int *size;
int *nextptr;
{
  void *ptr;
  if (*nextptr == NULL) {
    if ((ptr = (void *) malloc (*size)) == NULL) {
      return(-1);
    }
  }
  else {
    if ((ptr = (void *) realloc (*nextptr, *size)) == NULL) {
      return(-1);
    }
  }
  *nextptr = (int) ptr;
  return (0);
```

These are the following errors that I get

```
memalloc.c", line 19: warning: operand types are incompatible ("int" and "void
          *")
    if (*nextptr == NULL) {
                 ^
"memalloc.c", line 25: warning: argument of type "int" is incompatible with
          parameter of type "void *"
      if ((ptr = (void *) realloc (*nextptr, *size)) == NULL) {
                                   ^
"memalloc.c", line 29: warning: conversion from pointer to smaller integer
    *nextptr = (int) ptr;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I guess you meant `if (nextptr == NULL)`

Comment: `nextptr` is a pointer to `int`, so `*nextptr` is `int`.

Comment: The code is over 40 years old.  No surprise that modern typecheckers reject it.

Comment: Then I think you meant `nextptr = ptr;` instead of `*nextptr = (int) ptr;`

Comment: This code still uses K&R-style function definitions. It's time to put it out to pasture.

Comment: And you also mean `realloc (nextptr, *size))` not `realloc (*nextptr, *size))`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the function signature should be `int memalloc(void **nextptr, size_t *size)`

Comment: You don;t write pointer code by putting `*` in front of every pointer.

Comment: `*nextptr = (int) ptr;` Apparently they are storing the pointer returned by `malloc/realloc` as an `int`.

Comment: @BenVoigt You could be right, in which case all my comments are wrong.

Comment: @john: Your suggestion to remove the `*` in the last line of the function is definitely wrong, because then that line would have no visible side-effect (`nextptr` goes out of scope)

Comment: Note that back then NULL was frequently `0` and not `((void*)0)`. So comparing `*nextptr == NULL` would type check even though the code back wrong even back then.

Answer (score 0):

As per comments, `nextptr` should actually be `void **`. If that change is not feasible and it must remain `int *`, then you either cast:

```
if (((void*)*nextptr) == NULL) {
```

or simply compare to `0`:

```
if (!*nextptr) {
```

Comment: `nextptr` is a function out parameter, a pointer to a buffer which receives a result which is itself a pointer... but this ridiculously old code is designed for (apparently) a compiler that didn't support double-pointers.

Comment: in that case, compare to `0`

Comment: What's needed is to properly declare the parameter as a double pointer.

Comment: @BenVoigt yes, but it's not sure the user is allowed to do that. E.g. if it's a callback in a library where interface is pre-defined, you cannot change it.

Comment: One could still introduce a local variable which has the correct type.

Comment: @lorro The function must be called with a pointer pointer no matter what the prototype reads. So if you stop lying to the compiler and use `void**` it's only going to make it work better. It's an in/out parameter for a `void*`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow It is typical in some libraries that some data is passed by user to lib, then lib to callback. I.e., lib does not change this. It's usually `int *` or `void *`. In such a case, you're not allowed to change the data type. This also seems like such a case - it's a custom allocator.

Comment: @lorro That applies to function pointers. And here the `int*` is assigned an address with `*nextptr = (int) ptr;`. That clearly is only valid with a pointer pointer or `intptr_t`. But 40 years ago they where all the same.

Comment: I was able to fix the first two warning in my question with the answer above. But I am still stuck with the final warning
```
"memalloc.c", line 29: warning: conversion from pointer to smaller integer
    *nextptr = (int) ptr;
```

Comment: And yes, this code was used about 20 years ago and I am able to compile it but when I execute the executable, I get a message called segmentation fault. I am trying to eliminate all the warning so to see if that would help.

Comment: @SuryaSarvajith if `static_assert(sizeof(int) != sizeof(int*));` fails, i.e., if pointer and int sizes are different, then you're out of luck with this interface.